# Microservices - passing JWT in an asynchronous event - dealing with expiry of JWT if a service has a back log

Tags: authentication, asynchronous, jwt, microservices, token

Sorry for the vague title but it is difficult to give a short summary of the issue so I will explain here:

I am messing around and trying to learn microservices and I’m struggling with how to deal with auth from one service to another but only when using asynchronous comms (e.g. RabbitMQ etc).

With synchronous comms I can submit my request with a JWT and get an instant response, however if I submit a request to an event queue and that message contains the JWT for the receiving service to read and authenticate what happens if that service is down and the message sits there but by the time the service comes back online the JWT has expired then what do we do here? Everything is fine if the service is running and it is consuming immediately but if there is a back log of events or the service is down then I’m not sure how we then get this to work?

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

In a client/server relationship the client needs to authenticate into your system, but after that it's all up to you. Between services the client/server relationship changes so the auth will change as well. In the general case you will only use the JWT to authenticate that the user can perform the initial action, then your queuing service will need to authenticate itself to your other services.

Ideally your internal services are not directly accessible by the user anyway and should require different authentication.

Upstash's QStash has some simple documentation on this: https://docs.upstash.com/qstash/features/security

Answer (score 0):

couple of options come to my mind which you can try based on your use-case.

1. increase JWT expiry time - Not preferable
2. your consuming service can have multiple instances so that if one instance goes down you have other instances can still keep on doing the business. - Highly recommended
3. you can have correlationId kind of stuff in your message so that when the consuming service comes back and finds that the JWT has expired, can put the expired message in some other queue/topic (like dead-letter-queue) and the producer service can check these to take appropriate action like resending (based on correlationId) or any other business logic.